# Is it bad to put the User struct in the session?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I was looking at this blog post: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/phoenix-authentication/

And there's this section of putting a user's id in the session. However then you need to use the ID to lookup the user when you want to access it.

```
  conn
  |> put_session(:current_user, user.id)
  |> put_flash(:info, "Logged in")
  |> redirect(to: "/")
```

What would be bad about just putting the whole user struct in the session? Would that just be simpler?

```
  ...
  |> put_session(:current_user, user)
  ...
```

Comment: If you store password (even hashed) in that struct and you send it as a cookie then it is terrible idea. Store only data that you need and that will not change soon like user name, user e-mail, but don’t store data like privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phoenix sessions are by default stored in cookie, and cookie has a limit of 4K size. While most (if all) modern browsers support larger cookie file sizes, the [RFC 2109](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) still defines a limit of 4096 bytes, that might be exceeded when storing the whole struct in the session.

Comment: So as long as the `user` is smaller than 4K it should be ok. And even if it's larger, the modern browsers will still support it?

Comment: There is no guarantee, and fat cookies is not exactly what the users want, so I’d stick to storing `id`.

Comment: thanks for you response. The trade-off then is that we need to then query the database every time we need to get the user. 

I looked through the comments and the author's response to this trade-off: `The solution here is to store the User struct rather than just the id in the session.` Would that not be a reasonable alternative?

Comment: @PeteJ if you put the whole user struct in session, then what if users' data change? Correct me if I'm wrong, but then you also have to manage the invalidation of the data in session after an update to the user's profile. Then it's not really worth the save of a cost of a query to the DB.